# Why does chromedriver not launch?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So i made a python script with selenium and when i run it with the terminal using this command:

```
/usr/bin/python3 /home/user/Desktop/dogecoin/dogecoin.py
```

It starts doing something and then stops i get no errors its just blank and the web browser doesn't open. Heres a photo of the problem: [click me!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b12ra.png)

Here's the code:

```
#Imports
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common import service

#Import service=service
service=Service("./chromedriver")

#Chrome options :)
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

#Run chrome
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://www.coindesk.com/price/dogecoin')
```

Comment: You're running in ```'--headless'``` mode, so you would not see what the browser is doing. Comment that option out and see what next.

Comment: if that is your entire code, it probably just ends and closes the headless window.

Comment: Please run in the headless mode.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, the `headless` mode will not show the browser so you need to get rid of that.

Also, I don't know exactly how your `service` is supposed to work, but it is not a valid keyword for the first argument of `webdriver.Chrome()`. Here is some code that may use modules you don't want (eg `chromedriver_autoinstaller`), but it works to launch your URL.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_autoinstaller
import time

chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://www.coindesk.com/price/dogecoin')
time.sleep(5); # wait so you can actually see driver running
```